# how can i fully load page after login?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, laravel

I using php and curl to login web site and access web page contains javascript and ajax, i want to fully load page before i return page.

Is there another way to login the site and fully load web page contains ajax and etc ?

Can I store the cookies inside Broswer and access to the page by php code(laravel) like that `return Redirect::to($url);`

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.site/com/login.php';
$url='http://www.site/com/wood.php';
define("COOKIE_FILE", "c:\cookie.txt");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE); 
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, COOKIE_FILE );
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 115);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$store = curl_exec($curl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$content = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

**Edit 1:**

**i want to login web site and save cookie in browser programming, any one know how can i do that using any programming language php, javascript, c# etc ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can only load whatever HTML the page itself gives you.

cURL will execute your POST request and authorize you on the website. But it is not capable of  making AJAX requests.

If you want to also receive the parts that are dynamically added to the page via AJAX requests - you will need a browser (which will execute those queries). Or, you can emulate those queries with cURL - by yourself.

Use Firefox's Firebug addon and see which AJAX requests are done, what are their parameters and etc. After logging in to the website - preserve the cookies, and make the necessary AJAX requests.

Comment: can you give me an simple example ?

Comment: can i create simple php web browser or pass cookies of website to browser like firefox to access page directly ?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no 'simple' for web browser.

Comment: Is there another way of example php api or other way to login web page and access web page by broswer ?

Comment: There are some attempts. I've been trying to do a similar thing in the past and nothing worked. Why? Because you get HTML, then you need to get all JS - internal and external, then somehow apply to the HTML... in the end its too complex. If you want a programmable browser - use Java, which will make it a little bit easier, but it still remains a very complex job.

Comment: is there way to php deal with browser(firefox) cookies and save web site cookies in browser and redirect to web page in firefox ?

Comment: No, there isn't. You can save cookies from cURL request and use them again for consequent requests. However, firefox and other browsers are independant. If you are a very good software developer you can potentially integrate your code with webkit, which is the core of several browsers, like Chrome or Safari. It will be a very difficult task though, so I am not sure if you want to go that direction.